# Convexity of a set of probability densities

Tags: probability-distributions, convex-geometry, convexity, optimal-transportation

Consider the space of probability densities $(P(\mathbb{R}^d), W_2)$ (probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with 2-Wasserstein distance).

How can we determine if a subset $Q$ is convex?

I know that a set $A$ is convex iff for all $x,y \in A$, the point on the 'line segment' $\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y$ for $\lambda \in [0,1]$ is contained in $A$.

1. Let's say $Q$ = {mixtures of $N$ Gaussians}. Do we know the optimal transport between any two mixtures of $N$ gaussians? Is the 'line segment' between them also a mixture of Gaussians along the optimal transport path?
2. Let's say $Q$ = {product densities} (i.e. densities that have independent marginals). What about the 'line segment' in W2 space here?

I don't have much intuition about the optimal transport plan between two distributions. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. Convexity is a purely algebraic property. Where comes the 2-Wasserstein distance in?

Comment: The line segment between two mixtures of $N$ Gaussians consists of mixtures of $2N$ Gaussians.

Comment: Not quite a counterexample to assertion 2. (no densities, but this can be solved): $\mu :=\frac{1}{2} \delta_{(0,0)} + \frac{1}{2} \delta_{(1,1)}$ is a convex combination of two probability measures with independent marginals, but $\mu$ is not of this form.

Comment: @DieterKadelka I figured that the distance metric would affect the definition of the path between two points, but I guess that doesn't have to be the case. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: On the one hand, you can take the simple convex combination of two measures $\mu, \nu$ as $\lambda \mu + (1-\lambda) \nu$. On the other hand you can take the displacement interpolation motivated by the Wasserstein distance: Take $\pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)$ to be an optimizer of $W_2(\mu, \nu)$, then if $(X, Y) \sim \pi$, the interpolation is the distribution of $\lambda X + (1-\lambda) Y$. Notice that the two concepts are very different even for Dirac measures (they result in either $\lambda \delta_x + (1-\lambda) \delta_y$ or $\delta_{\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y}$). What do you mean?

Comment: @Steve interpolation wrt $W_2$ is closer to what I was thinking of! I'm interested in convexity of a set in the ambient space $(P,W_2)$ which is why this definition makes more sense. So far, I'm not convinced that {product densities} is not convex wrt $W_2$...

Comment: @900edges, there is a notion called either "displacement convexity" or "geodesic convexity" which I believe is what you are looking for.

Comment: Just a comment: as pointed out by pseudocydonia, a key word is "displacement convexity". Essentially you can think of a (displacement) convex set as the sublevelset of a (displacement) convex function. So your question somehow amounts to: how to determin whether a functional is displacement convex or not? this turns out to be a difficult question, it is an active field of research, and geometry really plays a role (for example convexity of the entropy is equivalent to Ricci lower bound in the sense of Lott-Sturm-Villani, almost by definition).

Comment: @leomonsaingeon looking these terms up, thank you for sharing! Is displacement convexity a concept specific to Wasserstein space? And does it mean "$F$ is displacement convex if it is convex along optimal transport plans"?

Comment: yes, it is specific, and displacement convexity is somehow tricky. I can also suggest giving a look at Villani's "books, as well as chapter 9 in the book by Ambrosio-Gigli-Savaré (where an alternative notion of generalized geodesics is provided, very useful at least for PDE purposes)

Comment: just for the record: the notion of displacement convexity is due to Robert McCann in his beautiful paper "A convexity principle for interacting gases"